# Slash replacement inside a raw string

Tags: python, regex, replace

Just a simple question concerning raw string, regex pattern and replacement:

I have a string variable defined as follow:

```
> print repr(foo)

'\n\t\t\n\t\tIf (GUTIAttach>=1) //In case of GUTI attach Enodeb should not ask RRCUecapa again\n\t\tUECapInfo;//Mps("( \\"rat_Type\\":0 \\"ueCapabilitiesRAT_Container\\":hex:011c0000000080 )");
```

My problem are characters `"("` and `")"`, I want to replace them by `"\("` and `"\)"` inside the raw string because it will be used after as a regular expression pattern.

I tried to use this method:

```
foo_tmp= [inc.replace(')', '\)') for inc in foo]
foo_tmp= [inc.replace('(', '\)') for inc in foo_tmp]
foo = "".join(foo_tmp)
```

the result gives:

```
 > print repr(foo)

'\n\t\t\n\t\tIf \\(GUTIAttach>=1\\) //In case of GUTI attach Enodeb should not ask RRCUecapa again\n\t\t{\n\t\t\tUECapInfo;//Mps\\("\\( \\"rat_Type\\":0 \\"ueCapabilitiesRAT_Container\\":hex:011c0000000080 \\)"\\);
```

Characters `"("` and `")"` have been replaced by `"\\("` and `"//)"` instead of `"\("` and `"\)"`.
That's a bit unexpected for me, so do you know how I can proceed to get just a single slash without changing the other part of the string?

Note: The method `.decode('string_escape')` is also not working due to the rest of string. Double slashes already present in the original raw string must not change.

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 5):

Use the [`re.escape()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.escape) to escape regular expression meta characters *for you*.

What you are seeing is otherwise perfectly normal Python behaviour; you are looking at a python literal *representation*; the output can be pasted back into a Python interpreter and recreate the value. As such, anything that could be interpreted as an escape code is escaped for you; a single `\` would normally be doubled to prevent it being interpreted as the start of an escape sequence:

```
>>> '\('
'\\('
>>> print '\\('
\(
```

You can see this at work in other places in your `foo` string; the `\n` character combination represents a newline character, *not* two separate characters `\` and `n`. If you wanted to include a literal `\` and `n` in the text, you'd have to double the backslash to `\\n`. Further on into the value of `foo` you'll find `\\"`, which is a *single* backslash followed by a `"` quote.

Comment: I agree with your comment. Thanks for your explanation.
However, the fonction `re.espace()` is not appropriated for my issue.

I tried it and here the result:

`print repr(foo2)` #Original string

`'\n\t\tIf (_ActivateEvents>=1) {Log "RECV SecurityMode_ind";}\n\t\t-> send_RRC_SecurityModeComplete;\n\t'`

and

`test = re.espace(foo2)`

`print repr(test)`

`'\\\n\\\t\\\tIf\\ \\(\\_ActivateEvents\\>\\=1\\)\\ \\{Log\\ \\"RECV\\ SecurityMode\\_ind\\"\\;\\}\\\n\\\t\\\t\\-\\>\\ send\\_RRC\\_SecurityModeComplete\\;\\\n\\\t'`

Comment: The `re.escape()` function is rather conservative and adds a slash in front of anything that is not a letter or digit. As far as the `re` module is concerned, the extra slashes dn't make a difference unless you have something like `\d` in there that should've been interpreted as a regular expression 'digits' class, really. Try it out anyway.

Comment: I tried what I could without success.
I changed my expression as follow: `foo_tmp= [inc.replace(')', '.*?') for inc in foo]`.
It's more a workaround than a solution but it's working fine like that.
Thanks for your help anyway

Comment: Why `'.*?'` and not `r'\('`?